# Directory name created with a dot ,using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, windows-7, cygwin, sh

I am using Cygwin Terminal to run shell to execute shell scripts of my Windows 7 system.
 I am creating directory , but it is getting created with a dot in name.

`test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
temp=$(date '+%d%m%Y')
dirName="Test_$temp"
dirPath=/cygdrive/c/MyFolder/"$dirName"
echo "$dirName"
echo "$dirPath"
mkdir -m 777 $dirPath
```

on executing `sh test.sh` its creating folder as `Test_26062015` while expectation is `Test_26062015`.Why are these 3 special charterers coming , how can I correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quote the `$dirPath` in the last command and add `-p` to ignore `mkdir` failures when the directory already exists: `mkdir -m 777 -p "$dirPath"`. Besides this, take care when combining variables and strings: `dirName="Test_${temp}"` looks better than `dirName="Test_$temp"`.

Also, use [this](http://www.shellcheck.net/) for static analysis of your scripts.

---

*UPDATE: By analyzing the debug output of [`sh -x`](https://shrib.com/shell123), the issue appeared due to DOS-style line-endings in the OP's script. Converting the file to UNIX format solved the problem.*

Comment: Its still creating with the dots

Comment: What does the `echo` calls print for you? Also, try executing your script with `bash test.sh` instead of `sh test.sh` and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: echo prints it fine `/cygdrive/c/MyFolder/Test_26062015` , but when I do `ls` I get `Test_26062015???`

Comment: What's the result of `mkdir -p "$dirPath"` without changing the permissions using `-m 777`?

Comment: it creates with dot even if I remove `-m 777`, although if I don't use variable and directly run `mkdir -m 777 /cygdrive/c/MyFolder/Test_$(date '+%d%m%Y')` , it works fine, why? . I have to do with variable

Comment: Would you please add a `set -x` after the shebang and run the script again (with variable). There should be some helpful debug output. Share this output somehow.

Comment: I added `#!/bin/bash set -x` , but getting same output.Is that the what you wanted me to do ? Sorry I am new to shell

Comment: No, make sure to have `#!/bin/bash -x` . Upload the output somewhere and share it.

Comment: Still getting same o/p

Comment: Convert your script to unix format using dos2unix tool.

Comment: I used gedit to write the script and chose linux as line ending, it worked :)

Comment: So, it was a line-ending issue.